# Can anyone please help me identify this component, SMD (R40 515 Z5J)?

Tags: components, surface-mount

[image: http://thestowes.co.uk/images/components.jpg]

Can anyone please help me identify this component. It's marked
R40 515 Z5J
Dimensions are roughly 6.5mm x 6.5mm x 3.0mm my verniers have disappeared but it's pretty close.

Comment: Asking for help identifying a part is on topic.  Asking where to buy one will get your question closed.  You can edit the question and remove the part about a link to where to buy a replacement.

Comment: +1 for a very good picture

Comment: Looks like 0.4µH coil.

Comment: Component ID questions are not off topic!

Comment: You could further improve your question by adding exact dimensions, if you own a good caliper.

Answer (score 2):

If the dimension 10.2x10.2x4.7mm lines up with your component then it may be Ferrocore HCI1050-R40 which is a 0.4uH inductor. There are others in the same series with the same inductance and different size. HCI####-R40.

Comment: 6.5mm x 6.5mm x 3.0mm all very rough as can't find my verniers, very appreciated though, please if anyone else can identify it I would be most grateful.